# Distribution / law of a stopped process $(X_0 , \ldots , X_\tau)$

Tags: probability

The problem orignates from LeGall's Measure theory , probability and stochastic process exercise 13.10 (3)
which asks us to verify two stopped discrete Markov process have
the same law . But what does it mean by the law of a random vector with random length ?

For example given a
sequence of random variables
$ \{X_n \}_{n=1}^\infty $ taking value in $E$
and a finite a.s stopping time $\tau$ w.r.t the filtration generated by $ \{ X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $ . For the law of $ (X_1 , \ldots , X_\tau) $ , it seems that
we need to consider the Borel set $B$ of the infinite product space $ E^\mathbb{N} $ and ask $P[ (X_1 , \ldots , X_\tau) \in B ] $ . But the notatin doesn't
make sense since $ (X_1 , \ldots , X_\tau)$ is a.s a finite dimensional vector . Is there any formal defiinition on it ?

Comment: It is an event in $B$ as you can take the countable union over the possible $X_n$ with $n>\tau$

Comment: For a Borel set $B$ of the infinite product space $ E^\mathbb{N} $, $P[ (X_1 , \ldots , X_\tau) \in B ] $  does not make sense.